# one table is related to two other tables is that a good idea?

Tags: database-design

Usually in a 1 to 1 releationship two tables are related. But today I saw a database in which one table is related to two other tables, something like this:

[image]

Example data:

```
media: 

id  | item_id | type  | filename 
100 | 200     | video | video200.mp4
101 | 201     | video | video201.mp4
201 | 501     | image | awesome_photograph.png
202 | 502     | image | awesome_photoshoot.png
203 | 503     | image | awesome_icon.gif

video: 

id  | duration
200 | 10.026666
201 | 32.00


image: 

id  | bitdepth 
500 | 24
501 | 24
502 | 24
503 | 8
```

Personally, I think this is a very strange database design because of this:

- the column type is holding 'duplicate' data for example 'image' is stored 3 times. Maybe it would be better to introduce a `mediaType` table, but that might have been an overkill.

However, I can see one advantage:

- the table `media` acts like a `parent` to both `video` and `image`

Questions:

Is it ok to design it like this or is this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok. Doctrine calls this approach Inheritance Mapping.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/inheritance-mapping.html